# Sum of entries of $A$ in terms of $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a positive definite matrix $A$ with non-negative entries and a function $f(k)=Tr(A^k)$

Is it possible to accurately approximate $g(A)=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}$ in terms of $f(k)$?

This is easy when $A$ is diagonal, want to know if it's easy in a more general case, like when $A$ is diagonal + rank-1

Motivation: I have a closed form expression for $f(k)$ but need $g(A)$, where $A$ is $d\times d$ convergent diagonal + rank 1 matrix from Equation 5 of [Bordelon](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.02713), too large for $O(d^2)$ operations

Comment: did you try this for even really simple cases?  E.g start with the PSD case and compare $\mathbf e_1\mathbf e_1^T$  vs $\frac{1}{d}J$ (for the ones matrix $J$).  Both are idempotent with trace 1 yet they sum to 1 and $d$ for large $d$. It's not remotely close. To make these PD just add $\delta I$ to each for small $\delta \gt 0$.

Comment: I did [try it](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-rank1-trace-user8675309.nb) for values appearing in my application. My matrices are powers of a small rank-1 correction of a diagonal matrix, so a single evaluation of trace gives good approximation of "sum of entries". I was wondering if knowing value of trace for powers of this matrix can improve my approximation

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The knowledge of the sequence (Trace$A^k)_{k\geq 1}$ is equivalent to the knowledge of the eigenvalues of $A$. Writing  $A=U^TDU$ with $U$ orthogonal and arbitrary, while you want to compute
trace $(AJ_n)$ where $J_n$ is the matrix $1_n1_n^T$ where $1_n$ is the column vector of 1. As a result

$$\mathrm{trace} (AJ_n)= \mathrm{trace}(U^T DU1_n1_n^T)=\mathrm{trace}((U1_n)^TD(U1_n))=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_iv_i^2.$$ where the vector $V=U1_n$ is arbitrary of norm $\sqrt{n}.$ You cannot recover $\mathrm{trace} (AJ_n)$ from the knowledge of the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)_{i=1}^n.$

In the particular case where $A=D+bb^T$ where $D$ is diagonal with non negative entries and where $b$ is a column vector, we have $$\mathrm{trace}[(D+bb^T)J_n]=1_n^TD1_n+(1_n^Tb)^2.$$ In these circumstances I do not understand your problem: since you know $D$ and $b$, why do you need the eigenvalues of $A?$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes the issue clear. In my case, $A$ is a power of a small rank-1 correction of diagonal matrix, so $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ is within factor of 2 of $\operatorname{Tr}(AJ)$. Here's what $v_i^2$ from your equation looks like -- [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbsmw.png)